# Get single row per column value ordered or grouped in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Case**:

I have `Show` and `Episode` models. An `Episode` belongsTo a `Show`. A `User` can track shows and mark episodes as watched.

**What in trying to achieve:**

I want to make 1 query that gets all the episodes that the user should watch next. Meaning, ordered by season and episode number, and then get the next episode that hasn't been watched yet.

**The problem:**

When I add `orderBy` and `orderByRaw` clauses, they are ignored when I use a `groupBy()`. groupBy does return a single episode per show, but automatically orders it by ID. It is possible episode 2 of season 1 and have a higher id then episode 3 or season 1. Thus ordering by ID is not reliable.

**What have i tried**

I have tried using ROW_NUMBER to create a new `where` clause:
`'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY episodes.show_id ORDER BY season * 1 asc, number * 1 asc) AS row_num'`, but because this is a window function, it isnt allowed in `where` or `having` statements.

**Why not just get everything and filter the collection?**

The amount of episodes can get large, this will be a huge performance loss. It needs to be filtered in the SQL query.

This abomination is where I stranded:

```
Episode::query()
            ->select('episodes.*')
            ->whereIn('episodes.show_id', $request->user()->trackedShows()->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->leftJoin('episode_user', function ($join) use ($request) {
                $join->on('episode_user.episode_id', '=', 'episodes.id')
                    ->where('episode_user.user_id', $request->user()->id);
            })
            ->orderBy('episodes.show_id')
            ->orderByRaw('season * 1 asc, number * 1 asc')
            ->whereNull('episode_user.episode_id')
            ->groupBy('show_id')
            ->get();
```

This kind of does what I need, because it returns 1 Episode row per show_id, but it seems to return the first ordered by id, which is not what I want.

TL;DR:
I want to perform 1 SQL query to get 1 episode per show based on the fact if it's been watched or not, and ordered by season and episode number. So it returns the "next" episode for me to watch for every show.

Comment: Try `->get()->groupBy('show_id')` (instead of the other way around). This will create groups of collections in Laravel rather than do an SQL `GROUP BY` (which is mainly done for aggregating and not for creating groups of rows)

Comment: @apokryfos as mentioned in my original question in the section "Why not just get everything and filter the collection?", this way is not performant enough. `->get()->groupBy('show_id')` would mean getting ALL the episodes for the shows, and then filtering. This could easily result in collections of 10.000 or even 100.000 episodes, this will not be performant enough to be able to work.

I know SQL `GROUP BY` isn't the answer, i'm looking for what SQL way is. It really needs to be SQL.

Comment: Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables, plus the attempted `SELECT` (in SQL, after being generated by Laravel)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
What i needed to do is create a subset with ROW_NUMBER(), which i then could use to get all the ID's which in turn could be used to get the Eloquent models:

```
$episodeQuery = DB::table('episodes')
            ->fromSub(
                DB::table('episodes')
                    ->select('episodes.*')
                    ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY episodes.show_id ORDER BY season * 1 asc, number * 1 asc) AS row_num')
                    ->whereIn('episodes.show_id', auth()->user()->trackedShows()->pluck('id')->toArray()),
                'eps'
            )
            ->where('row_num', 1)
            ->pluck('eps.id');

$episodes = Episode::whereIn('episodes.id', $episodeQuery->toArray())->get();
```